# A public action method 'xyz' was not found on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have Kendo Grid in my view. I have specified read , edit and delete each as of type HTTPPOST. But when I try to edit or delete i get an error that  : "A public action method 'UpdateDetails' was not found on controller 'Nop.Plugin.Misc.CategoryWiseShipping.Controllers.ShippingChargeController'." for update Action and similarly one other for delete option.

Interesting thing is that **it works fine on my local machine but throws error when published to server**

I have searched extensivelly on google but couldn't find the reason as to why it is happening.

This is the controller actionMethod

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateDetails(ShippingChargeModel shippingChargeModel)
    {
        if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageProducts))
            return AccessDeniedView();

        if (shippingChargeModel.SchoolEmail == null)
        {
            ErrorNotification(" Email can not be null !!", true);
            return RedirectToAction("AddShippingCharge", "ShippingCharge");
        }

        if (shippingChargeModel.SaleStartDate == null)
        {
            ErrorNotification(" Sale start date can not be null !!", true);
            return RedirectToAction("AddShippingCharge", "ShippingCharge");
        }

        if (shippingChargeModel.SaleEndDate == null)
        {
            ErrorNotification(" Sale end date can not be null !!", true);
            return RedirectToAction("AddShippingCharge", "ShippingCharge");
        }

        if (shippingChargeModel.SaleEndDate < shippingChargeModel.SaleStartDate)
        {
            ErrorNotification(" Sale start date should be less than sale end date!!", true);
            return RedirectToAction("AddShippingCharge", "ShippingCharge");
        }

        var modelFromDb = _catShippingService.GetRecord(shippingChargeModel.Id);

        modelFromDb.SaleEndDate = shippingChargeModel.SaleEndDate.Value.AddMinutes(330);
        modelFromDb.SaleStartDate = shippingChargeModel.SaleStartDate.Value.AddMinutes(330);
        modelFromDb.SchoolEmail = shippingChargeModel.SchoolEmail;
        modelFromDb.ShippingCharge = shippingChargeModel.ShippingCharge;
        modelFromDb.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;

        _catShippingService.Update(modelFromDb);
        return new NullJsonResult();
    }
```

This is my Kendo Grid :

```
function loadKendo() {
         var dataNew = {};
         $("#shippingCharge-grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetDetails", "ShippingCharge"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",

                    },
                     update: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("UpdateDetails", "ShippingCharge"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        //data: addAntiForgeryToken
                    },
                     destroy: {
                         url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("DeleteDetails", "ShippingCharge"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                     }
                    ,
                    parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                        if (operation === "update") {
                            dataNew.Id = data.Id;
                            dataNew.CategoryId = data.CategoryId;
                            dataNew.ShippingCharge = data.ShippingCharge;
                            dataNew.SaleStartDate = stringToTimestamp(data.SaleStartDate.toUTCString());
                            dataNew.SaleEndDate = stringToTimestamp(data.SaleEndDate.toUTCString());
                            dataNew.SchoolEmail = data.SchoolEmail;
                            return { ShippingChargeModel: dataNew };
                        }
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "Data",
                    total: "Total",
                    errors: "Errors",
                    model: {
                        id: "Id",
                        fields: {
                            //ProductId: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                            CategoryId: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            CategoryName: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            ShippingCharge: { editable: true, type: "number" },
                            SaleStartDate: { editable: true, type: "date", format: "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm}"},
                            SaleEndDate: { editable: true, type: "date", format: "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm}"},
                            SchoolEmail: { editable:true, type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                requestEnd: function (e) {
                    if (e.type == "update") {
                        this.read();
                    }

                    if (e.type == "cancel") {
                        this.cancelChanges();
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                    // Cancel the changes
                    this.cancelChanges();
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true
            },
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                numeric: false,
                previousNext: false,
                info: false,
                 pageSizes: [@(gridPageSizes)]
            },
            editable: {
                confirmation: "@T("Admin.Common.DeleteConfirmation")",
                mode:  "inline"
            },
            scrollable: false,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "CategoryName",
                    title: "CategoryName",
                    width: 300
                },
            {
                field: "ShippingCharge",
                title: "Shipping Charge",
                width: 100,
                encoded: false
                }
                ,
            {
                field: "SchoolEmail",
                title: "Email",
                width: 200,
                encoded: false
            }
                ,
            {
                field: "SaleStartDate",
                title: "Sale Start Date",
                width: 200,
                encoded: false,
                type: "datetime",
                format: "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm}",
                template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(SaleStartDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd/MMM/yyyy') #",
                editor: dateTimeEditor
            },
            {
                field: "SaleEndDate",
                title: "Sale End Date",
                width: 200,
                encoded: false,
                type: "datetime",
                format: "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm}",
                template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(SaleEndDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd/MMM/yyyy') #",
                editor: dateTimeEditor

            }, {
            command: [
                {
                    name: "edit",
                    text: {
                        edit: "@T("Admin.Common.Edit")",
                        update: "@T("Admin.Common.Update")",
                        cancel: "@T("Admin.Common.Cancel")"
                    }
                }
                , {
                    name: "destroy",
                    text: "@T("Admin.Common.Delete")"
                }
            ],
            width: 200
        }
            ]
        });
    }
```

Please help me out. Any sort of insight will do ...

Comment: I recommend taking Kendo out of the picture.  Given the error you can reduce this down to a postman test.  Since it works local, you may have a configuration or deployment issue.  Check firewall, web host (iis?), and config settings.

Comment: Could be deployment issue. Make sure the DLL that contains the controller is the right version on the server.

Comment: Yeah It was Deployment Issue. I was pushing to FTP using filezilla and overwriting the file and it was not working ... Strange !! ... I deleted the plugin and pushed a fresh copy and it worked .. 
how do i mark this thread as closed / Answered ??? Thanks BDW for the inputs :)